# iOS showing a notification dependent on both location and time

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, gps, location

I'm making an iPhone application that needs to show a notification to the user depending on their location as well as the date. The date will be within a date range specified by a server (downloaded when the user first opens the app), and the location is a location within an area; any location within the described area will return true, and if the user is in the area and it is in the specified date range, the phone will display a notification.

I know I can execute code once the user opens the application to check both these conditions, but I don't want that. I want it to display a notification ONLY if these 2 conditions have been fulfilled, which the user can then click to enter the application. Is this even possible?

I looked at push notifications as well, and it doesn't look like I will be able to do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use **Core Location** to monitor the location of the device by calling the [`startMonitoringForRegion:desiredAccuracy:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocationManager/startMonitoringForRegion%3adesiredAccuracy%3a) method of your `CLLocationManager`.

When the user enters the specied region, your app is notified and [`locationManager:didEnterRegion:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManagerDelegate_Protocol/CLLocationManagerDelegate/CLLocationManagerDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/CLLocationManagerDelegate/locationManager%3adidEnterRegion%3a) is called. You can check the date in that method and if it is in the specified date range, you can display the notification.

Have a look [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH2-SW13) and particularly [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH2-SW16) form more details.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into it. However, my regions are not clearly defined; they are irregular shaped polygons. Is there a way to define a CLRegion that is not just a circle? Also, wouldn't this open up the app and not run in the background?

Comment: @DanielChui - 1) Your best option I guess is to approximate you polygon regions with circles. 2) The app will not be launched (in the foreground) when notified about location changes, but you can display a notification to the user.